# Unexpected result in Java (floating to integer)

Tags: java

I have a problem with this

```
System.out.print((9/5) * 3);
```

I expects the result `5.4` but it returns `3`. Why is this happening?

Comment: all 3 numbers are integers so you get an integer as a result.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`9/5` is evaluated in *integer arithmetic*, so it's equal to 1.

Writing `9.0 / 5 * 3` is a common fix. (Promoting one of the coefficients in the term to a `double` forces the evaluation to take place in double precision floating point.)

Answer (score 2):

System.out.print((9.0/5) * 3);

Comment: Adding some more explanation would be better. :)

Answer (score 1):

In java when you make division of integers it will return an integer not a real number :

`9/5` return `1` instead of `1.8`

to solve your problem you have two solutions :

1. use a real number instead so you have to use `9.0/5`
2. or you can cast the number to double `((double)9/5) * 3`

Answer (score 1):

All the numbers are integer there so it will give integer result you may make 9.0 or 5.0 to get that answer...
As given below..

```
System.out.print((9.0/5) * 3); OR
System.out.print((9/5.0) * 3);
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to remove the redundant parentheses since (i) I'm dogmatic about that, and (ii) you are vulnerable to someone refactoring to `(9 / 5) * 3.0`. But have an upvote all the same.